# Automated import and translation of 600 SVG files

Tags: python, scripting, svg

I would like to import a dataset consisting of 600 SVG files (sequential slices of a mouse brain).

000.svg would be the front of the brain and 600.svg the back. I’d like to incrementally translate each svg’s x value, spacing them out to approximate the three-dimensional volume of the brain.

https://scalablebrainatlas.incf.org/mouse/ABA_v3

Basically, something like this.

Is this possible using python scripting?

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of a trick necessary for this, because `bpy.ops.import_curve.svg` does not return any information about what objects it added to the scene.  The trick is to  create a set of all of the collections in the scene before calling it and then take the difference of that set with the set of all of the collections in the scene after calling it.  The difference will be the new collection.

Given that explanation, here's a script tested on 2.93.5 that will work, moving each new SVG file an increment along the Z axis.  Obviously, to work for you, you will have to change the file path pointing to the directory and compute the delta you want to use.

You could make the glob pattern more likely to reject bad filenames, ie `'???.svg'` if you felt it necessary.

```
import bpy
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('PUT YOUR PATH HERE')

scene = bpy.context.scene

collections = set(scene.collection.children)

offset = 0.0
delta = 0.01  # Replace with your calculation of an appropriate delta

for f in sorted(p.glob('*.svg')):
    bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath=str(f))
    new_collection = set(scene.collection.children) - collections
    collections = set(scene.collection.children)
    for aCollection in new_collection:
        for object in aCollection.objects:
            object.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0,0,offset))
        offset += delta
        for object in aCollection.objects:
            object.select_set(False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Marty. That's just the ticket. Well, it turns out my computer can't handle the full dataset. It took all night, and Blender is unresponsive when trying to work with the resulting product. I'm confused about how a 40 MB folder of .svg files turns into a 500 MB .blend file. But your script is exactly what I was looking for, and works great with up to fifty or so .svg files. The dataset I'm referencing is downloadable here: https://scalablebrainatlas.incf.org/templates/ABA_v3/source/coronal_svg.zip in case anybody wants to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible for sure, I'm working on such script myself atm. You can batch import your SVG's with a code like this:

```
import bpy
import os

import_path=os.path.join('C:\\temp\\')
file_list = sorted(os.listdir(import_path))
svg_list = [item for item in file_list if item.endswith('.svg')]

for svg_file in svg_list:
    svg_path=os.path.join(import_path,svg_file)
    bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath=svg_path, filter_glob='*.svg')
```

Then you could loop through the collections/objects, parse their name and position them on x axis using the result.